# How to remove all test classes from Pharo?

Tags: unit-testing, smalltalk, pharo

I am using Pharo and I want to shrink image size by safely removing all the Test classes, which I don't need them for my production image. I guess that image size could decrease considerably.

I have tried using Monticello Browser but there is no way to select multiple packages.
Anyone tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily write your own code to remove test classes, but did you have a look at the `ImageCleaner` class and it's `cleanUpForProduction` method? It does not only remove test packages but also other code you will not need in your production image like help and example packages.

If you take a look at it's `testPackages` method you can see:

```
^(RPackageOrganizer default  packageNames select: [ :each | each endsWith: 'Tests' ]) copyWithout: 'ReleaseTests'
```

Once you have all the test packages you can remove them:

```
testPackages do: [ :each | (MCPackage named: each) unload ].
```

In addition you could look for all remaining subclasses of TestCase.